# JOSN Request Format

Tags: rest-api, json

How to send field label names in the JSON request body for the custom fields instead of their API names.

```
{  
   "0030H00004jntjiQAA":{  
      "Sample__c":true,
      "Send_To_Email__c":true,
      "Languages__c":false,
      "Level__c":false
}
}

{  
   "0030H00004jntjiQAA":{  
      "Sample":true,
      "SendToEmail":true,
      "Languages":false,
      "Level":false
}
}
```

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: Look on this,Eric provided the good solution on Json's.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153001/json-serialize-not-giving-me-correct-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate an API name into a label using code like this (where the label is obtained from a [field describe result](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)):

```
Contact[] cs = ...;

SObjectType[] fields = new SObjectType[] {
        Contact.Sample__c,
        Contact.Send_To_Email__c,
        Contact.Languages__c,
        Contact.Level__c
        };

// Logic for list of objects
Map<String, Object> ms = new Map<String, Object>();
for (Contact c : cs) {
    // Logic for one object
    Map<String, Object> m = new Map<String, Object>();
    for (SObjectField f : fields) m.put(f.getDescribe().getLabel(), c.get(f));
    ms.put(c.Id, m);
}

String jsonString = JSON.serializePretty(ms);
```